# Limiting IBM Connections 5 OAuth state parameter length

Tags: oauth-2.0, connection, opensocial, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'm attempting to create an opensocial gadget, hosted in IBM Connections, that connects to Dropbox.

However, it seems when doing the OAuth dance, connections is sending a 219 byte state parameter to the authorize endpoint. Dropbox limits this to 200, so the OAuth dance fails.!

Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend opening a PMR in this particular case. The available configuration data is listed here... state is not one of them http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_oauth_configequiv.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-4-3-1-0-1&lang=en